# d3 : coloring dots on a scatterplot using column in dataset

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, colors

I've copied some code to make a basic scatterplot and I'm trying to color the dots based on one of the columns of the data.

I've tried modifying the dataset to have a column named "Color" with values between 0 and 1 but when I assign the color function (i.e. d3.interpolateRdGy(d[2]) ) the scatterplot has no dots on it.

I'm very, very new to d3 (I have experience only with ggplot2 in R).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/2_TwoNum.csv", function(data) {

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 4000])
    .range([ 0, width ]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 500000])
    .range([ height, 0]);

  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.GrLivArea); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.SalePrice); } )
      .attr("r", 1.5)
      .style("fill",  d3.interpolateRdGy(d[1]))

})

</script>
```

Comment: You need to wrap it in a function to be able to access the bound datum `d`: `.style("fill",  d => d3.interpolateRdGy(d[1]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with D3, you would create a color scale. If you want to map a quantitative value to a color, then you could do

```
const color = d3.scaleSequential()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.Color))
    .interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues);
```

`d3.extent(data, d => d.Color)` returns an array that contains the min and max values of the "Color" column in your dataset. This approach will work even when the values are not between 0 and 1, unlike directly calling the interpolator.

You can find other color schemes in the [d3-scale-chromatic docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic). For diverging color schemes, you can use a [diverging scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#diverging-scales).

Then to use the color scale, you would do

```
    .attr('fill', d => color(d.Color))
```